# What is this "Software Engineering" site you speak of, and what kinds of questions can I ask there?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, faq-proposed, new-site-name

Programmers has changed its name.

- Why has this name change occurred?
- Has anything else changed?
- What kinds of questions will I be able to ask, now that the name has changed?

Comment: see also: [Are you still confused about what Programmers is for?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5654/31260)

Comment: That post is a bit outdated.

Comment: it is interesting to notice that site scope as of today is pretty much the same as was outlined over 3 years ago (freelancing and licensing are gone / or almost gone but that's only because these matters are now better handled by newer specialized sites)

Comment: Yes, I think that was a major point in this whole ordeal: we did *not* want to change the scope, but rather align the site name, URI, tag line, help center, and on-topic page with what the scope already was.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `we did not want to change the scope` what? that's exactly what's happening here.

Comment: @Qix not in the slightest, consider taking a closer look at discussions in [meta-tag:new-site-name] tag. In particular, discussion that [started](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260) this effort says it pretty clearly: **"The site scope and FAQ has been clarified so it is very clear what is on or off topic now"**. And none of the following discussions had changed that stance (you maybe are somewhat confused about recent edits to Help Center but these are only rephrasing to satisfy bureaucratic requirement of SE management to have 4 bullets there instead of 6)

Comment: Please, please oh god don't change the name to software engineering. Software engineering is a terribly inaccurate name for software development, which is not in any way a rigorous engineering discipline like actual engineering disciplines.

Comment: @MilesRout: The new name is not intended to be accurate, nor is it targeted at people who require accuracy in their site names.  The new name is intended for those individuals who think that peanut butter sandwiches are on-topic because programmers eat peanut butter sandwiches.  It is our hope that those folks who see the name Software Engineering in the site title will view the site as a professional resource and hopefully ask their questions about peanut butter sandwiches somewhere else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But questions related to 'people'ish things in software *should* be on-topic. There are several very, very highly upvoted and very helpful questions that have been closed years later because you keep narrowing the definition of what is on topic here.

Comment: @MilesRout: Because the new folks who see those questions think they can ask similar questions.  But the questions they ask in these subject areas are terrible 99 percent of the time, and we can't afford to keep them on-topic for the 1 percent of remaining questions that people happen to find useful.

Answer (score 34):

### Why is "Programmers" changing to "Software Engineering?"

Because the name "Programmers" invites all sorts of questions that are only vaguely related to software engineering, questions that we don't want.

### Has anything else changed?

Yes.  The Tour and the Help Center have a new tag line, the public description of the site which is seen by everyone. The Help Center/Ask page includes four new bullets that describe the site's "scope:" the kinds of questions that are suitable to ask here.

#### If the Help Center describes the scope, then what is the purpose of this post?

To better describe the site in a way that makes it very clear what kinds of questions are acceptable to ask here.  Over the years there has been a lot of confusion over what the site is all about, and we think we can now describe it in a way that is very clear and unambiguous.

### OK, so what kinds of questions can I ask, then?

> Questions *directly related*
> to the Systems Development Life Cycle, *except for code
> troubleshooting and requests for written code.*

#### What does "Questions related *directly* to the Systems Development Life Cycle" mean?

This is what it means (click on the picture to expand it):

[image]

If the subject area of your question is in that picture, it's probably an acceptable question.  If the subject area of your question is not in that picture, or is only tangentially related to one of those topics, then it is probably off-topic.

#### Why can't I ask questions about writing or troubleshooting specific bits of code here?

Because that role is already well-served at Stack Overflow.  This site, in part, is a refuge for those folks who have no interest in fixing other people's broken code or writing their code for them.

Comment: This always gives me the impression that we have a wide scope with a few exceptions.  The last bit makes me think of [law](http://law.stackexchange.com/), [opensource](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/), and [history](http://history.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange. To bad the last two are still in beta.  It'd be nice to point to them.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Open Souce is certainly doing reasonably well, and is unlikely to close anytime soon.

Comment: I know Law or Opensource might be more appropriate for licensing questions, but if I encounter a license question, I doubt I should do anything to close it?  What about historical questions regarding software licenses?

Comment: @maple_shaft as far as I know meta discussion to update and finalize on licensing is sort of "in the queue", it was just kind of obscured by name change efforts which are [considered more important than licensing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31224602#31224602 "'it's something y'all have to figure out... But it's a super inside-baseball kinda discussion; licensing and law just aren't a big part of this site on a day to day basis'")

Comment: @CandiedOrange Based on the help center at [History Stackexchange](http://history.stackexchange.com) I very much doubt that questions related to the history of programming, such as this [recent question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331388/why-was-the-caret-used-for-xor-instead-of-exponentization) would be appropriate there. Would it be appropriate at [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.org)? Don't know, maybe.

Comment: While those sites are technically in beta, with the "new" graduation criteria, it looks pretty impossible for them to fail.

Comment: @CandiedOrange SQA Stack Exchange, which encompasses the entirety of the 7th step in Robert's diagram, has been in beta for 5 years. It isn't going to be graduating any time soon (fluctuates between 5 and 7 QPD, not the 10 required for graduating) but is certainly going to be available to handle questions related to testing but not "directly" related to the SDLC where they might previously been encouraged here.

Comment: @corsiKa not sure where you're going with this.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Your comment about law, opensource, and history stack exchanges mentioned that they're in beta. I was emphasizing the fact that a site being in beta doesn't mean it won't be able to receive the increased load due to a lack of scope of this site.

Comment: @corsika wasn't concerned about load.  Was concerned that we my have a policy against referring people to beta sites.  If we don't I'm all in favor of telling posters of off topic questions where to go. ;)

Comment: If there is such a policy, it's unique to this site and would be very much contrary to the public goal of the network. Further, diamond moderators can migrate to any site they want, I don't see why users wouldn't be able to recommend the same.

Comment: @corsika In that case I advocate providing links to all more appropriate sites to any topics we specifically call out as being anything less than on topic here.  Finding out you're in the wrong place is easier to deal with when there is a clear signpost pointing you to the right place.

Comment: After all these years, I never realised the S in SDLC is "systems" not "software".

Comment: Who is the "we" that is constantly being referred to?

Comment: @Mehrdad probably 386 users who voted up [this request to change site name](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260) (387 if you count author of request who apparently can not vote up own post)

Comment: @gnat: Oh, I see, thanks. Interesting. I'd be surprised if a name change fixes the site being so ridiculously antiwelcoming, but whatever works I guess.

Comment: Have you been thinking about SO question tagged with e.g. UML that are clearly (more than 99%) related to this new site? I started a discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335039/why-does-so-have-an-uml-tag-given-that-uml-is-clearly-for-programmers-se

Comment: It is not only the name that invites the questions you don't want, but the steaming casual-discussion coffee mug as well.

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer is wrong. [Questions seeking legal advice have been off-topic since early 2012](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2912/4), we have had no discussion that make licensing or history off-topic. There are new communities that are dedicated to [Law](http://law.stackexchange.com/) and [Open Source](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/), until we come to a consensus, questions that can reasonably be expected to be answered by a software engineer are still on-topic. [History has been on-topic since 2013](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5633/4).

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I've removed History from the answer.  Licensing questions should just go away; other sites can handle them.

Comment: I still see Programmers as the name.

Comment: I have serious problems with the idea that only questions that align with that hideous waterfall-based "Systems Development Life Cycle" diagram are allowed. I'll certainly be answering proper programming questions that don't fit that antiquated thing.